# akka-http no stack trace or details on error

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, asynchttpclient

I got a structure which can basically be summarized as:

- outside user makes a rest request to akka-http server
- akka-http makes a request(query?) to a (some)data source using asynchttpclient
- akka-http transforms the result from asynchttpclient and serves it back to user

At some point I am getting an error from akka which tells me almost nothing. This error happens right after the asynchttpclient returns me some results. (I can infact at this point print the results on the log, they are there parsed from json etc.. but akka had already errored out)

Even in debug logging level I got no decipherable error message from akka or a stacktrace.

only message I got is:

```
2017-03-24 17:22:55 INFO  CompanyRepository:111 - search company with name:"somecompanyname"
2017-03-24 17:22:55 INFO  CompanyRepository:73 - [QUERY TIME]: 527ms
[ERROR] [03/24/2017 17:22:55.951] [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(company-api-system)] Error during processing of request: 'requirement failed'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response.
```

This error message is the only thing I get. Relevant parts of my config:

```
akka {
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  # edit --  tested with sl4jlogger with no change
  #loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  #logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"

  parsing {
    max-content-length = 800m
    max-chunk-size             = 100m
  }
  server {
    server-header = akka-http/${akka.http.version}
    idle-timeout = 120 s
    request-timeout = 120 s
    bind-timeout = 10s
    max-connections = 1024
    pipelining-limit = 32

    verbose-error-messages = on
  }

  client {
    user-agent-header = akka-http/${akka.http.version}
  }

  host-connection-pool {
    max-connections = 4
  }
}

akka.http.routing {
  verbose-error-messages = on
}
```

Anyone knows if I can make akka to spit out more details about what/where the error is occurring?

Edit: <s>I realized I do NOT get this same error on resultsets which are smaller in size.</s> <- ignore

### Edit 2:

- Added akka.loglevel = DEBUG, spits out a lot more noise but still not detail about the actual error.
- Converted asynchttpclient to akka quickly to rule out AHC
- I already had a wrapper around my query to time it, added some logging there trying to pinpoint when exactly the error is happening.

  ```
  def queryTimer[ R <: Future[ Any ] ]( block: => R ): R = {
    val t0 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = block
    result.onComplete { maybeResult =>
      val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
      logger.info( "[QUERY TIME]: " + ( t1 - t0 ) + "ms" )

      maybeResult match {
        case Success(some) =>
          logger.info( "successful feature:")
          logger.info( FormattedString.prettyPrint(some))
        case Failure(someFailure) =>
          logger.info( "failed feature:")
          logger.debug( FormattedString.prettyPrint(someFailure))
      }
    }
    result
  }
  ```
- resulting log:

  ```
  2017-03-28 13:19:10 INFO  CompanyRepository:111 - search company with name:"some company"
  [DEBUG] [03/28/2017 13:19:10.497] [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [EventStream(akka://xca-api-actor-system)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
  [DEBUG] [03/28/2017 13:19:10.497] [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [EventStream(akka://xca-api-actor-system)] Default Loggers started
  [DEBUG] [03/28/2017 13:19:10.613] [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [AkkaSSLConfig(akka://xca-api-actor-system)] Initializing AkkaSSLConfig extension...
  [DEBUG] [03/28/2017 13:19:10.613] [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [AkkaSSLConfig(akka://xca-api-actor-system)] buildHostnameVerifier: created hostname verifier: com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier@779e2339
  [DEBUG] [03/28/2017 13:19:10.633] [xca-api-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://xca-api-actor-system/user/pool-master/PoolInterfaceActor-0] (Re-)starting host connection pool to localhost:27474
  [DEBUG] [03/28/2017 13:19:10.727] [xca-api-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://xca-api-actor-system/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Resolving localhost before connecting
  [DEBUG] [03/28/2017 13:19:10.740] [xca-api-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://xca-api-actor-system/system/IO-DNS] Resolution request for localhost from Actor[akka://xca-api-actor-system/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0#-815754478]
  [DEBUG] [03/28/2017 13:19:10.749] [xca-api-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://xca-api-actor-system/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Attempting connection to [localhost/127.0.0.1:27474]
  [DEBUG] [03/28/2017 13:19:10.751] [xca-api-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://xca-api-actor-system/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Connection established to [localhost:27474]
  2017-03-28 13:19:10 INFO  CompanyRepository:73 - [QUERY TIME]: 376ms
  2017-03-28 13:19:10 INFO  CompanyRepository:77 - successful feature:
  [ERROR] [03/28/2017 13:19:10.896] [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(company-api-system)] Error during processing of request: 'requirement failed'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response.
  2017-03-28 13:19:10 INFO  CompanyRepository:78 - SearchResult(List(
  ( prettyprint output here!!! lots and lots of legit result, json parsed succcesfully into a bunch of case classes)
  ```

  as you can see my logging format and akkas' are different, the ERROR is coming from akka with do details, while everything looks like working.

### Edit 3: logs with `sleep` in between calls

- new query timer function with sleeps

  ```
  def queryTimer[ R <: Future[ Any ] ]( block: => R ): R = {
    val t0 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = block
    result.onComplete { maybeResult =>
      val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
      logger.info( "[QUERY TIME]: " + ( t1 - t0 ) + "ms" )

      maybeResult match {
        case Success(some) =>
          Thread.sleep(500)
          logger.info( "successful feature:")
          Thread.sleep(500)
          logger.info( FormattedString.prettyPrint(some))
          Thread.sleep(500)
          logger.info("we are there!")
        case Failure(someFailure) =>
          logger.info( "failed feature:")
          logger.debug( FormattedString.prettyPrint(someFailure))
      }
    }
    result
  }
  ```
- logs with sleeps

  ```
  [DEBUG] [03/30/2017 11:11:58.629] [xca-api-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://xca-api-actor-system/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Attempting connection to [localhost/127.0.0.1:27474]
  [DEBUG] [03/30/2017 11:11:58.631] [xca-api-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://xca-api-actor-system/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Connection established to [localhost:27474]
  11:11:59.442 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
  11:11:59.496 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
  11:12:00.250 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-15] INFO  c.s.s.r.neo4j.CompanyRepository - [QUERY TIME]: 1880ms
  [ERROR] [03/30/2017 11:12:00.265] [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(company-api-system)] Error during processing of request: 'requirement failed'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response.
  11:12:00.543 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
  11:12:00.597 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
  11:12:00.752 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-15] INFO  c.s.s.r.neo4j.CompanyRepository - successful feature:
  11:12:01.645 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
  11:12:01.697 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
  11:12:01.750 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-15] INFO  c.s.s.r.neo4j.CompanyRepository - SearchResult(List( "lots of legit result here"
  11:12:02.281 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-15] INFO  c.s.s.r.neo4j.CompanyRepository - we are there!
  ```

### Edit 4 and solution!

- Apparently the default exception handler does not print a stack trace! overriding the exception handler with a very basic catch all:

  ```
  implicit def myExceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler =
    ExceptionHandler {
      case e: Exception => {
        logger.info("---------------- exception log start")
        logger.error(e.getMessage, e)
        logger.error("cause" , e.getCause)
        logger.error("cause" , e.getStackTraceString )
        logger.info( FormattedString.prettyPrint(e))
        logger.info("---------------- exception log end")
        Directives.complete("server made a boo boo")
        }
    }
  ```
- results in a stack trace that befuddles the sh*t out of me!!

  ```
  11:42:04.634 [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO  c.stepweb.scarifgate.CompanyApiApp$ - ---------------- exception log start
  11:42:04.640 [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] ERROR c.stepweb.scarifgate.CompanyApiApp$ - requirement failed
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
      at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:212) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
      at spray.json.BasicFormats$StringJsonFormat$.write(BasicFormats.scala:121) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
      at spray.json.BasicFormats$StringJsonFormat$.write(BasicFormats.scala:119) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
      at spray.json.ProductFormats$class.productElement2Field(ProductFormats.scala:46) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
      at com.stepweb.scarifgate.services.CompanyService.productElement2Field(CompanyService.scala:14) ~[classes/:na]
      at spray.json.ProductFormatsInstances$$anon$3.write(ProductFormatsInstances.scala:73) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
      at spray.json.ProductFormatsInstances$$anon$3.write(ProductFormatsInstances.scala:68) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
      at spray.json.PimpedAny.toJson(package.scala:39) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
      at spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1$$anonfun$write$1.apply(CollectionFormats.scala:26) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
      at spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1$$anonfun$write$1.apply(CollectionFormats.scala:26) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
      at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
      at spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1.write(CollectionFormats.scala:26) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
      at spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1.write(CollectionFormats.scala:25) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
      at spray.json.ProductFormats$class.productElement2Field(ProductFormats.scala:46) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
      at com.stepweb.scarifgate.services.CompanyService.productElement2Field(CompanyService.scala:14) ~[classes/:na]
      at spray.json.ProductFormatsInstances$$anon$1.write(ProductFormatsInstances.scala:30) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
      at spray.json.ProductFormatsInstances$$anon$1.write(ProductFormatsInstances.scala:26) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport$$anonfun$sprayJsonMarshaller$1.apply(SprayJsonSupport.scala:62) ~[akka-http-spray-json_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport$$anonfun$sprayJsonMarshaller$1.apply(SprayJsonSupport.scala:62) ~[akka-http-spray-json_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.Marshaller$$anonfun$compose$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(Marshaller.scala:73) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.Marshaller$$anonfun$compose$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(Marshaller.scala:73) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.Marshaller$$anon$1.apply(Marshaller.scala:92) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.GenericMarshallers$$anonfun$optionMarshaller$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(GenericMarshallers.scala:19) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.GenericMarshallers$$anonfun$optionMarshaller$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(GenericMarshallers.scala:18) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.Marshaller$$anon$1.apply(Marshaller.scala:92) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.PredefinedToResponseMarshallers$$anonfun$fromStatusCodeAndHeadersAndValue$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(PredefinedToResponseMarshallers.scala:58) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.PredefinedToResponseMarshallers$$anonfun$fromStatusCodeAndHeadersAndValue$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(PredefinedToResponseMarshallers.scala:57) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.Marshaller$$anon$1.apply(Marshaller.scala:92) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.Marshaller$$anonfun$compose$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(Marshaller.scala:73) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.Marshaller$$anonfun$compose$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(Marshaller.scala:73) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.Marshaller$$anon$1.apply(Marshaller.scala:92) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ToResponseMarshallable.scala:29) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ToResponseMarshallable.scala:29) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.Marshaller$$anon$1.apply(Marshaller.scala:92) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.GenericMarshallers$$anonfun$futureMarshaller$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(GenericMarshallers.scala:33) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.GenericMarshallers$$anonfun$futureMarshaller$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(GenericMarshallers.scala:33) ~[akka-http_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.akka$http$scaladsl$util$FastFuture$$strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41) ~[akka-http-core_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$$anonfun$transformWith$extension1$1.apply(FastFuture.scala:51) [akka-http-core_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$$anonfun$transformWith$extension1$1.apply(FastFuture.scala:50) [akka-http-core_2.11-10.0.0.jar:10.0.0]
      at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
      at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.16.jar:na]
      at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.16.jar:na]
      at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.16.jar:na]
      at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.16.jar:na]
      at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
      at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.16.jar:na]
      at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.16.jar:na]
      at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.16.jar:na]
      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
  11:42:04.640 [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] ERROR c.stepweb.scarifgate.CompanyApiApp$ - cause
  11:42:04.641 [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] ERROR c.stepweb.scarifgate.CompanyApiApp$ - cause
  11:42:04.644 [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO  c.stepweb.scarifgate.CompanyApiApp$ - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
  11:42:04.644 [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO  c.stepweb.scarifgate.CompanyApiApp$ - ---------------- exception log end
  ```
- so... the exception is caused here in spray.json.BasicFormats

  ```
  implicit object StringJsonFormat extends JsonFormat[String] {
    def write(x: String) = {
      require(x ne null)    // <-----------------------------------
      JsString(x)
    }
    def read(value: JsValue) = value match {
      case JsString(x) => x
      case x => deserializationError("Expected String as JsString, but got " + x)
    }
  }
  ```

which sort of means one of the strings in this thousands of lines of response is null. Special thanks goes to the laziness of using that "require" without a message. Debugging which string is empty where will be a nightmare but I still think akka should fail in a better way.

Comment: have you tried setting `akka.loglevel` to `DEBUG`?

Comment: the log level in my log4j.properties file is debug, akka.loglevel add anything? also where is this supposed to be set?

Comment: this should be in your config (you can add the key `loglevel` to your existing `akka` object) and is before log4j can do anything..

Comment: What does your code that makes the AsyncHttpClient call look like?  Are you using Future?  If so, you will likely need to explicitly trap errors and log on failure, otherwise they will get swallowed.

Comment: AsyncHttpClient uses futures, and reads from a stream. I don't think AHC is the problem, because moments after akka throwing this "error" logs spit out the data returning from AHC call. I think I mentioned this in my question but may be it is not clear.

Comment: Kali, is this issue a 100% reproducible or is it flickering? If it is reproducible could you do one more test? What happens if you add `Thread.sleep` for like 1 second 3 times before first `logger.info` in between and after the second. The question is: will it change order of log messages exonerating your code or will error still somehow be in between of your logs?

Comment: One more thing, have you tried to provide a custom exception handler? The log message seems to be generated by [default ExceptionHandler](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/ExceptionHandler.scala#L27) but you can change it to log stack trace as well. By the way it is sounds a bit surprising that I can't find string "requirement failed" in the sources except for tests.

Comment: @SergGr writing an exception handler helped to print the stack trace, If you can write an answer for reference I will accept it. I still believe akka should fail better than this but hey..

Comment: @SergGr The "requirement failed" message is apparently coming from scala require() function spray.json uses this function without fallback error messages hence the meaningless error message :)

Comment: kali, not sure what exactly you wanted me to post but I created some answer. Feel free to edit (I'll accept any reasonable edits)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> akka-http no stack trace or details on error

Well, default akka-http [`ExceptionHandler`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/ExceptionHandler.scala#L27) doesn't print stack trace and prints only error message or its class name if the message is empty but you can provide custom exception handler that will print anything you want (i.e. stack trace in your example).

Some examples of how to make a custom exception handler are provided at [GitHub ExceptionHandlerExamplesSpec.spec](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/docs/src/test/scala/docs/http/scaladsl/server/ExceptionHandlerExamplesSpec.scala)

The simplest way in your case seems to be to define your own custom implicit exception handler

```scala
  import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
  import akka.http.scaladsl.server._
  import StatusCodes._
  import Directives._

  implicit def myExceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler =
    ExceptionHandler {
      case NonFatal(e) =>
          logger.error(s"Exception $e at\n${e.getStackTraceString}")
          complete(HttpResponse(InternalServerError, entity = "Internal Server Error"))
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is an extra closing curly bracket at the end but I cannot remove it due to the SO 6 character edit minimum

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the loggers as well - from your configuration it seems they're not set. Something like:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

Also, consider using [akka-slf4j](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/logging.html#SLF4J) along with their recommended logging backend [logback](https://logback.qos.ch/).

This should make akka spit more details.

Comment: I don't see how a different logger would help but did it anyway. This only changed the format of the logged error line, not a single word more information. `10:45:10.354 [company-api-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] ERROR akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - Error during processing of request: 'requirement failed'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response.`